# How to create this marble paint effect with blender texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

[image]

How to create this marble paint effect with blender texture?

Comment: You could get the shape of it with the voronoi texture node.

Comment: You'll want to plug the distance into a color ramp, then turn up black and put the white all the way to the right.

Comment: Hello :). What have you tried so far and where *exactly* are you stuck?

Comment: The rings within the cells can easily be created with more stops on the previously described color ramp. However, the radial streaks may be harder...

Comment: Thanks all of you to give me a point to get started!